# Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source

Tags: ubuntu, apt, docker, error-handling

I was installing Docker Engine on Ubuntu 22.04 using the following link https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/, everything was okay until I reach `sudo apt-get update`, it gives me the following error:

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/ jammy: /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I had to edit the permission for this file:

```bash
$ sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
$ cd /etc/apt/keyrings
$ ls -la
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 16 23:43 .
    drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Jan 17 00:33 ..
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2760 Jan 16 23:43 docker.gpg
```

But the error is still found, what should I do?

I attempted to delete the keyrings directory,

```
sudo rm -r ./keyrings
```

and the sudo apt update error is still found:

```
sudo apt update
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/ jammy: /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

the output of `ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

```
total 36
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  96 Dec 10 21:30 archive_uri-http_dl_openfoam_org_ubuntu-jammy.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  96 Dec 10 19:29 archive_uri-http_dl_openfoam_org_ubuntu-jammy.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  72 Dec 10 21:30 download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  72 Dec 10 19:29 download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  70 Dec 10 21:30 gazebo-stable.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  70 Dec 10 19:29 gazebo-stable.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Dec 15 23:43 official-source-repositories.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 248 Dec 10 19:29 official-source-repositories.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 118 Dec 10 21:31 ros2.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 118 Dec 10 19:29 ros2.list.save
```

Comment: AFAIK Ubuntu as well as other distributions provide a (custom) docker package in their repositories. So you could simply use: 1) `sudo apt update` (if it's necessary 2) `sudo apt upgrade` (if it's necessary) 3) `sudo apt install docker`. Or do you have/want to install the docker package provided by Docker Community (`docker-ce`)?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon No, it's not necessary; all I want right now is to fix this mistake. After that, I'll see if sudo apt install docker works.  :/

Comment: Try removing the files: `sudo rm /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`. and after that run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install docker`

Comment: i have already removed them and it didn't work :/

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d`?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon my question is edited

Comment: Ok, then run: `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu.list.save` and update and try installing docker by using: `sudo apt install docker`

Comment: @EdgarMagallon It worked, many thanks.

Comment: Should you post the solution or me? It's useful for the site as well as future visitors whose have the same problem and can resolve it by following these steps

Comment: @EdgarMagallon i really appreciate your help while solving this problem, and of course you may post it and i'll mark it as solved :)

Comment: I was wrong, I've tested on my Ubuntu sever and the `docker` package does not provide the docker engine and its other dependencies. In my host machine with openSUSE the docker package is provided by the self distro. In your case, does the `docker` command exist? I mean, you can use: `docker run`, `docker start`, etc.?

Comment: No, it does not exist. I tried to avoid working on anything connected to docker because I found it to be so complicated, but I'm glad to report that I was able to eliminate those bothersome errors, so let's add a solution specifically addressing how to get rid from these error.

Comment: Oh ok! I'll do it! Btw, you can try podman to work with containers (generally docker and podman use the same commands). Hopefully someone provides a solution to avoid this error and can be installed docker successfully. (Or If I've found a solution I'll provide it too)

Comment: ok, I'll check it, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Important:** This answer does not solve *how to install docker*. Instead it does solve how to avoid the errors given by the command: `sudo apt-get update` when the docker repositories were added:

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/ jammy: /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

**Solution**

You will have to remove the following files:

```bash
sudo rm /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

And if someone keeps getting the same error then it should be removed the following files:

```bash
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
sudo rm download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu.list download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu.list.save
```

Comment: This worked for me, but, do you know why it happened?

Comment: @cherouvim I'm not really sure how signs work in apt/deb packages. Maybe there is/was a bug from docker repositories that makes this happens or maybe there are conflicting values betweem the docker repository and the ubuntu reposotories.  For example, in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/757823/414186) the user mentioned that the file had two same entries.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same

> E:Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/ jammy: /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc != /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/docker.asc, E:The list of sources could not be read.

Turned out the file

> admin:///etc/apt/sources.list.d/download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu.list

had a double entry:

> deb https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
>
> deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc]  https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy stable
>
> deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/docker.asc] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy stable

commenting out the 2nd line by prefixing it with '#' (because it's double) fixed it for me.
After that

> sudo apt-get update

worked again